# Disable generation of Javascript, Lisp, EusLisp messages

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, cmake, message-generation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a standard `CMakeLists.txt`, message parsing code for Javascript, Lisp and EusLisp gets generated, but I'm not interested in these. Is there an easy way to disable this generation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318516/disable-generation-of-javascript,-lisp,-euslisp-messages/) by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2019-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The environment variable `ROS_LANG_DISABLE` is documented in the wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_LANG_DISABLE

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-17**:
@Dirk Thomas' answer is correct, but I've still closed this as a duplicate, as there are at least two older Q&As that deal with the exact same question: #q213511 and #q260865 (which refers back to #q213511).

@KenYN: which keywords did you use to search, and did you not find the two linked Q&As?